# How to make nginx stop using service_name for redirecting?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to wrap my microservice flask project with Nginx in Docker compose. Problem is that all my microservices are using `http://<docker_container>/<urn>` endpoints on various containers within Docker network, while Nginx is trying to reach `http://<docker_container>/<service_name>/<urn>` and obviously gets 404. How can I make it compose url without using `<service_name>`?

Example of my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /api_gateway {
        proxy_pass http://api_gateway:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me? Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help of one github repo
Needed to add this to my nginx.conf:

```
rewrite /<service_name>(.*) /$1 break;
```